# How do I get Cisco webex working under Debian 7 64bit

Tags: debian

I'm running Debian 7 64bit on my server and I'm using Oracle Java 8 64bit and firefox 45.0.1.

When I connect to the test webex page https://www.webex.com.au/test-meeting.html and test it loads the java app and tries to connect, but it doesn't connect at it stops responding to some of the application. ie: the menus still work and I can click the leave meeting button.

If I go into my .webex directory and do the following commands I get the file libjawt.so is missing.

```
~/.webex/1524 % ldd *.so > check.txt                                                  
~/.webex/1524 % cat check.txt | grep "not found"                                      
    libjawt.so => not found
    libjawt.so => not found
```

The libjawt.so is part of the libgcj packages and I already have these installed

```
~/.webex/1524 % dpkg -l | grep libgcj
ii  libgcj-bc:amd64                                             4.7.2-1                                         amd64        Link time only library for use with gcj
ii  libgcj-common                                               1:4.6.3-8                                       all          Java runtime library (common files)
ii  libgcj12                                                    4.6.3-1                                         amd64        Java runtime library for use with gcj
ii  libgcj13                                                    4.7.2-3                                         amd64        Java runtime library for use with gcj
ii  libgcj13-awt                                                4.7.2-3                                         amd64        AWT peer runtime libraries for use with gcj
```

How do I get webex working on this system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download a Debian package of WebEx from here:
[Download Webex - DEB or rpm](https://www.webex.com/downloads.html/) and then install it via

```
dpkg -i /path/to/debian/package/WebEx.deb
```

Comment: Thanks Joerg, I have just installed it, but it requires Debian 11 which I have on one of my systems. Looks like Cisco is finally catching up.

Answer (score 1):

WebEx needs the 32bit version. First all you need to have a multi-arch system and then install that package as follows.

```
apt-get install libgcj:i386
```

Comment: This answer is very **incomplete** and does not really answer the question.